# How can I write users table data in custom file?

Tags: 7, database, testing

I have a number of users in my site,I have developed custom module for drupal mail functionality.

But I want to write test cases for custom module.

then here is the problem is how can I get the (`db_select`) users table data and write down in `.test` file.

for example in `.module` file we use like this:

```
$select = db_select('{users}', 'users');
$select -> addField('users', 'name', 'users_name');
$select -> addField('users', 'uid', 'uid');
$select -> addField('users', 'mail', 'users_mail');
$select -> addField('users', 'created', 'users_created');
$select -> addField('users', 'access', 'users_access');
$select -> addField('user_relationships', 'requester_id', 'requester_id');
$select -> addField('users_roles', 'rid', 'role_id');
$select -> addField('users_user_relationships', 'mail', 'users_user_relationships_mail');
$select -> leftjoin('user_relationships', 'user_relationships', "users.uid=user_relationships.requestee_id");
$select -> leftjoin('users', 'users_user_relationships', "user_relationships.requester_id=users_user_relationships.uid");
$select -> innerjoin('users_roles', 'users_roles', "users.uid = users_roles.uid");
$select -> condition('users.status', 0, '<>');
$select -> condition('users_roles.rid', array(
  '4',
  '5'
), 'IN');
$subresult = $select -> execute();
```

and i have wrote .test file like this

```
<?php
class BiTestMailsTests extends DrupalWebTestCase {
protected $privileged_user;
public static function getInfo() {
  return array(
    'name' => 'Test Mails',
    'description' => 'Tests for the mail module.',
    'group' => 'Test Mail Group',
 );
 }
public function setUp() {
   parent::setUp(array('mails'));

   }

public function testmail() {
    // Create an administrative user.
    $account = $this->drupalCreateUser(array('administer actions'));
    $this->drupalLogin($account);

      //database files
    $results= db_select('users','u')->fields('u',array('uid','name','mail','created','access'))->execute()->fetchAll();
    if($results){
     foreach($results as $res){
     $user_fields = user_load($res -> uid);
     $this->verbose('language:'.$language);
     $string= 'uid:'.$res->uid.' ,name:'.$res->name.' ,mail:'.$res->mail.',created date:'.$res->created.',Access:'.$res->access.'\n\r';
     $this->verbose($string);
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

but temporary user created and that values are getting.
i don't want temp values,i want database USERS table values.
**How can I write down `users` information(name and email) in `.test` file?**

Answer (score 1):

Your just need get your select put it in `FOREACH` and write down in file.(something like below code can help you_

```
$results= db_select('users','u')->fields('u',array('uid','name','email'))->execute()->fetchAll();
if($results){
     $fh=fopen(drupal_get_path('module',   'yourcustommodulename').'/usertest.txt','w+');
     foreach($results as $res){
     $string= 'uid:'.$res->uid.' ,name:'.$res->name.' ,email:'.$res->email.'\n\r';
    fwrite($fh,$string);
  }
  fclose($fh);
```

}

Comment: how can i retrieve his role and put it in one array.

Comment: i have edited my question,how can i write that query in .test file.

Comment: @User you can add each of `users` table fields, you just need add it to  `->fields('u',array('uid','name','email'))`,as example if you need `Roles` use `->fields('u',array('uid','name','email','roles'))`

Comment: but users table values are not getting,only temporary values are getting.

Comment: i have edited my question,please tell me some sollutions for that.